# how can I embed necessitas in Qt apk file?

Tags: android, qt, pyqt, qt-necessitas

I have a Qt project and I build an apk package from Qt creator.when I tried to install this package on an android device It need to download Necessitas but I want a stand alone package so how can I embed the necessitas in apk file?

Comment: Which At version is that? Using a recent Qt Creator and Qt 5, deploying a standalone version should be the default setting (see deployment settings)

Comment: Qt creator 2.5.83 and qt 4.8.3